# Amp for Focusrite 2i2 and Beyerdynamic DT 770 (250 ohms)

Tags: headphones

Do you think the Focusrite 2i2 will be enough to power the Beyerdynamic DT 770's headphones (250 ohms)? I've done some research and it seems they might come in a little low, though a few others have claimed otherwise.

I'm mostly using them for mixing and sound design.

Answer (score 1):

I have the 250 Ohm 880s and they work fine on consumer gear, at least for an appropriate listening level (compared to what the average consumer would believe a good volume mevel would be).  I believe the 600 Ohm ones are the set which pretty much require a headphone amp or pro audio headphone outputs which have a lot of gain.

Answer (score 0):

I use this exact combo at work and it's fine. Usually the headphone dial is set to 6 or 7 and 10 would be LOUD. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

The DT 770's are great headphones and are avaiable in a number of different impedences.  Generally provided that the construction of the headphones is same the lower the impedence the louder the headphone will sound at the same output level, but the amount of distortion will increase.  Having said that I have the 250ohm and 80ohm versions and distortion has never been an issue.

I'm not familiar with the Focusrite unit, but you might want to check the spec to see what output power/level that unit offers.  It is then just simple ohms law.  Increasingly manufactures are lowering the power output as headphone impedences are decreasing.